# Cloud flare, cache, minify question

Tags: cache

If I am using Cloud Flare to serve my site, and use their Cache and minify options, is there sense in caching and minifying at the Wordpress level as well?

Is this a waste of time or do I get a double positive impact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general no, there is no advantage in having two caching entities in the way of each request.

But you should be careful and understand how the caching works. For example cloudflare do not cache your pages in a central repository but each data center has its on cache so in an edge case you might get many requests at the same time from all of them, or a bug in one might flood your site.

The bigger your site is the more protection you will want against edge cases, and you will want to have as much caching layers as it makes sense, but for small sites it is probably not needed and just complicates the maintenance of the site.